# Getting bind error while connecting to ldap

Tags: linux, ldap, bind, ldap-query, selinux

I have written the following ldap command to test ldap connection

```
 ldapsearch -x -h ldap.com -b "uid=user1,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

I am getting the following output

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <uid=user1,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 1 Operations error
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907C2, comment: In order to perform this opera
 tion a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580

# numResponses: 1
```

Please suggest how to resolve bind error

Comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection (ie you have to bind as a user with a password.)

Comment: can you provide me the command to include user and password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error implies you need to bind to the server to be able to perform the search. As an example:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=directory manager" -w secret -p 389 -h server.example.com -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "(objectclass=*)"
```

The man page for [ldapsearch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch)

Comment: options -h and -p are deprecated, replaced by a new option: -H ldap://hostname:port